# MLlibで予測値を「確率」で出す方法

Tags: 機械学習

以下のページを参考にMLlibを実装したところ、predict関数の返り値が1か-1で、スパムの確率が高いほど1に近くそうでなければ0に近い値が出るというようにはできないようなのですが、MLlibではこのような「確率」を返す関数というのは用意されてないのでしょうか。
なお、NaiveBayesをSVMWithSGDに変えてみてもやはり1か0で超平面からの距離のような連続的な値にはならないようです。

[Scala ではじめる Spark / MLlib の単純ベイズ分類器 - ALBERT Engineer Blog](http://tech.albert2005.co.jp/blog/2014/07/17/mllib-naivebayes/)

Comment: 既にご存知かもしれませんが、[LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) の [predict function](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/java/svm_predict.java#L36)には `predict_probability` というフラグがあって、`1` を指定すると推定確率を返してくれます。

Comment: それは知りませんでした。MLlibでやる方法がないなら試してみようと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVMWithSGDについてはわかりました。[公式ドキュメント](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html)にあるようにデフォルトで設定されているしきい値0をclearThresholdすればpredictでナマの値が出るようになります。

```
model = SVMWithSGD.train(dataSet, NUM_ITERATIONS)
model.clearThreshold()
val score = model.predict(point.features)//0.8094...のようなナマの値
```